# How to find out why a PHP Class doesn't support underscore variables?

Tags: php, class, object

I have quite a weird question. I'm currently new to OOP in PHP, so please do not blame me for this question.

I have created a file and a class, called: Animals.

```
class Animals {

   protected $_snake;

}
```

I have also created another file with another class, called: Nature. I would wanted to use the variable defined in the Animals class so I did extend this class. (Is it the right method to use another class's variables?)

```
<?php

include 'Animals.php';

class Nature extends Animals {

   public function __construct () {

      echo $this -> _snake;

   }
}

?>
```

I have used the underscore to mark, that it is a protected variable (is it correct?). The problem occurs when I try to run this code, becuse I always get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: Nature::$_snake in C:\***\Nature.php on line ***
```

However if I remove the underscore before the variable name, it works perfectly.

Can anyone please explain what did I do wrong when applied that underscore to the variable?

EDIT:

When I insert the:

> protected $_snake;

to the Nature class, it works well with the underscore! I'm quite confused now.

Comment: What version of php are you using? This should be working.

Comment: I don't understand your Edit. You say you have the "Undefined Error" only when you don'T define the variable? It seems quite logical to me...

Comment: just curious when you add/remove '_' to/from class Nature, do you change in class Animal also?

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem. The `_` is only convention. It marks internal (private/protected) properties and allows to have a (dynamic) public property with the same name without the prefix.

Comment: It should be giving that error as it isn't defined until you set it to something. For example, `protected $_snake = 'test';`, should work without problem. The underscore shouldn't change anything.